# Partial update of Label text in XamarinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am having a rotator having label in each slide indicating the count to be displayed there. I have bounded it property which performs an API operation for fetching the count. I getting the getting the value fetched but the problem is that when displayed on the label it visible only partially. I am familiar with the rules about updating UI elements on the UI thread using the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread. I have called with Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread. For eg if the count is 25. but the label shows only 5. but when the page is refreshed the the same command gets executed and displays the correct value.I have followed viewmodel approach i.e i have command for fetching the count.
I have called that command during the page on appearing event also To refresh the count when I am back to home page even after initial load.

Xaml

```
<Label FontFamily="{StaticResource Montserrat-Regular}"
       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
       Text="{Binding Count}"
       FontSize="60"
       Style="{StaticResource RotorLabelStyle}" />
```

viewmodel

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            var result = await _matchingTrialsService.GetMatchingTrialsCount();

                            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                            {
                                item.Count = $"{result:0}";
                            });
                        });
```

xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                ((PatientHomeViewModel)this.BindingContext).CountDetilsCommand.Execute(null);
            });
        }
```

Does anybody have a workaround for this issue[image]

left is the result is truncated result

right is the correct result

Comment: Is Count a bindable property? Are you implementing the PropertyChanged event for that property? It will work in the OnAppearing method because it is just  setting the view at that time, but you need to bind the view with the Bindable property if you want the data to be instantly propagated to the view on property change event.

Comment: Yes it is a bindable property.

Comment: Can you please show us more code about your viewModel and data-binding?  Seems your binding does not works well.

Comment: public ObservableCollection<CountDetailModel> CountDetailCollection
        {
            get => _countDetailCollection;
            set
            {
                if (_countDetailCollection == value) return;
                _countDetailCollection = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: issue is that, in some situations the does shows's value fully. half is truncated. Once I try to fetch that count with button press it is fully visible. I use the same function for the both operation.

Comment: What is `CountDetilsCommand` , post [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)